# Exit Class While Loop and return to Main Method?

Tags: java

Alright I am back again with a new wall that I have met. I'm trying to figure out how I can break from `ticketInput()` and return to my `mainInputMenu()`. This is not my entire code but to gather an idea of what I am attempting to do I think this is enough to understand my issue.

Main Method----

```
public class Tickets {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    mainInputMenu();

}

    private static void mainInputMenu() {

    Machine whichMachine = new Machine();

    int machineNumber = Machine.readInput();

    while ( machineNumber == 1 ) {
        machineOne ( machineNumber );
    }
    while ( machineNumber == 2 ) {
        Machine machineTwo = new Machine();
    }
    while ( machineNumber == 3 ) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

private static void machineOne(int machineNumber) {
    Machine.option = 1;
    Machine.writeOutput();
    Machine.ticketInput();
}
}
```

Within Class File -------

```
public static void ticketInput() {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner ( System.in );
    String ticketCounter;
    int counter = 0;

    do {
        System.out.printf ( "Your choice: " );
        ticketCounter = keyboard.next();
        if ( ticketCounter.matches ( "[0-9]+" ) ) {
            counter = Integer.parseInt ( ticketCounter );
        }
        if ( counter < 1 || counter > 11 ) {
            System.out.println ( "Try again!" );
        }
    } while ( counter < 1 || counter > 11 );

    switch (counter) {
        case 1:
            rSelected = "Uptown";
            break;
        case 2:
            rSelected = "Downtown";
            break;
        case 3:
            aSum = aSum + 1;
            break;
        case 4:
            if ( aSum > 0 ) {
                aSum = aSum - 1;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println ( "Cannot go below 0." );
            }

            break;
        case 5:
            cSum = cSum + 1;
            break;
        case 6:
            if ( cSum > 0 ){
                cSum = cSum -1;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println ( "Cannot go below 0." );
            }
            break;
        case 7:
            creditSum = creditSum + 0.25;
            break;
        case 8:
            creditSum = creditSum + 1.00;
            break;
        case 9:
            creditSum = creditSum + 2.00;
            break;     
        case 10:
            System.out.println ( "-----------------\n"
                    + "YOU GOT YOUR TICKET!!!\n"
                    + "-----------------");
            System.exit(0);
        case 11:
            //Return to main menu
        default:
            break;
    }
```

I appreciate any input that will guide me to figuring this out. I feel as though it is a simple statement that I just can't seem to dig out of the internet.

Comment: You can `return;` from anywhere in a method (that return `void`, or `return something` where something match the return type of the method) to end the method. PS: that's not really a [mcve] ;)

Comment: BTW, do you understand what `while` does?  E.G. If machineNumber == 1 then it will never get past this code `while ( machineNumber == 1 ) {
        machineOne ( machineNumber );
    }`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how your flow control works but yes, where you have `System.exit(0);` you can just substitute a `return;` and the method will end and pass control back to the caller.

Comment: @markspace I understand how I could return from that set of while loops. But my issue is that the second portion of code is in a different file. A .class file And I want to know if it is possible to return based on the users input of 11 and go back to my main argument in the .java file

Comment: try using a debugger and stepping through your code

Comment: Will give it a shot @ScaryWombat but the code works fine up to this point. Main argument --> User Input 1 2 or 3 and decide on which machine to go to --> Enters separate .class file to retrieve further inputs from 1 - 11. My issue stands when I press that 11 input to return back to the .java file at the mainInputMenu()

Comment: Fixed. I entered Tickets.mainInputMenu(); and it asked me to make something private I didn't catch what but it is now working as intended. Guess I just needed to keep messing around. Appreciate all of your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change your mainInputMenu() like this

```
private static void mainInputMenu() 
{ 

     Machine whichMachine = new Machine();

     int machineNumber = Machine.readInput();
     do
     {
        if (machineNumber == 1)    machineOne (machineNumber);
        else if (machineNumber == 2)    Machine machineTwo = new Machine();
        else if (machineNumber == 3)  System.exit(0);
        int machineNumber = Machine.readInput();
     }while (machineNumber > 0 && machineNumber < 4);


}
```

Here you can repeatedly run machineOne()

and now you can return from ticketInput()

```
case 11: return;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `return` from function it will return to the calling function.

The call to `System.exit(0)` will terminate your application.

So, replace `System.exit(0)` with `return;`.

And you have to add a loop for continuously get the menu and other functionality in the main method as follows:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  while(true) {
    // Add some breaking option here.
    mainInputMenu();
  }

}
```